# Windows 8 freezes with high HDD activity

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad

I have Window 8 (upgraded from Windows 7) installed on my Lenovo x201 and in general things are working very well.

However, periodically the machine completely freezes with high hard disk activity. This is often triggered when changing windows using Alt-Tab. Suddenly Windows freezes (or goes extremely slowly) and the hard disk is full on for about 30 to 60 seconds.

In the Task manager, it is the process called 'System' that seems to be involved. I can't seem to find out any other useful information.

- I have about 80GB free on the HHD
- In the Task Manager the CPU activity is low
- The Task Manager says I am using about 2.8GB of 3.8GB memory.
- HHD is maxed out at 100% throughout the freeze.

At all other times (including virtually immediately after the freeze) the laptop and Windows 8 is fast and responsive.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These problems seem to occur because you upgraded from windows 7 rather than performing a clean windows 8 installation, does this problem appear under 5-10 minutes after logging in?? or maybe this could  be because your explorer got corrupt due to virus or during the installation.

Am i right or are you in a different scenario.

Comment: You are correct in that I upgraded from Windows 7. As for time after login, I am not 100% sure, but it often occurs when I wake the computer from sleep mode. Another symptom is that Window 8 Metro apps seem to take a very long time to start.

Comment: OK ,now the solution that fits in this problem is to try  refreshing  your pc 
STEPS TO REFRESH YOUR PC:

1).Start by bringing your cursor to top right corner of your screen

2). Then select settings

3). Select change pc settings

4). Navigate to general tab and scroll down on the right window,you will see the option to refresh your pc (after applying this option check for 1 to 2 days while logging into a **local account** than switch to Microsoft account if you have one)

If the problem remains try the option of re installing windows which will work like a factory reset of a cell phone.

Comment: These are the only options according to my knowledge.
If these solutions fail you will have to make a clean installation of windows.
If the problem is solved don't forget to mark the right button (click to accept this answer). :)